# Direction Cosines and Reflection In The Plane

Tags: geometry

The equation of the plane is x - 2y - 2z = 27.

The point P has coordinates (-3,2,1).

The question requires me to find the direction cosines of the reflection of the line OP - where O is the origin - in the plane.

So, I worked out that the reflection of the point P in the plane is P' with coordinates (5,-14,-15). I have no issue calculating the direction cosines, but I feel like the co-ordinates of P' are wrong. Because it gives me direction cosines cosa=5/(446)^1/2, etc. because the magnitude of OP' is 446^1/2.

Can someone verify whether or not I got the coordinates of P' correct?

Answer (score 0):

You might try to calculate the equation of the straight line passing through $O$ and $P$, and then you should find the intersection between this straight line (call it $r$) and the plan $\pi$ of given equation (if $r$ and $\pi$ are not parallel); so the straight line passing through $r \wedge \pi$ and $O'$ (where $O'$ is the simmetrical of $O$ respect to $\pi$) is the simmetrical of $r$ (call it $r'$). Given $r'$ you can calculate the cosine directions remembering that $ \displaystyle |\cos \theta| = \frac{|\langle \vec{x}, \vec{y} \rangle|}{\|\vec{x} \| \| \vec{y} \|}$.

Let's try and let me know if it runs.